# How to link opencv 2.4.9 in header file in Visual studio 2013 in C++

Tags: opencv, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

When ever i include the opencv file this shows error: "This specified file doesn't exist."

```
  #include<opencv2\core\core.hpp>

  namespace Project2 {
using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for MyForm
/// </summary>
public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{


   public:
      MyForm(void)
  {
          InitializeComponent();
//
//TODO: Add the constructor code here
//
    }

protected:
~MyForm()
{
if (components)
{
delete components;
}
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem with the code? How can i link the opencv2.4.9 to my header file.

Comment: add your/opencv/build/include to the "Additional Include Folders" in the c++ section. also, do yourself a favour, and postpone cli/managed c++/gui to a later stage, start with an *empty* project.

Comment: I have added the aove mentioned file but still it is giving error\

Comment: try `#include<opencv2/opencv.h>` instead please. And try to use `/` instead of \.